# SharePoint list has a hyperlink column, when clicked goes to an email. When this is clicked, I need a choice field change from yes to no

Tags: hyperlink

Is this possible with a calculated column?  I have a hyperlinked field in a list, that when clicked, opens an email.  Once this field is clicked, I need the choice field (Yes/No) automatically change to No. Possible with calculated column? Workflow?  Thanks so much

Comment: what's your SharePoint version?  if sharepoint online you will not be able to add HTML Tag in a calculated column and if it's on-prem this is will depend on the current build number read more at [THE SUPPORTED AND UNSUPPORTED COLUMNS IN SHAREPOINT CALCULATED COLUMN FORMULA](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to change choice column on click of hyperlink column

1. Create a hyperlink column. I have created  ‘EmailColumn’
2. Create a choice column. I have created ChoiceYN. Default value is set to yes.
3. Copy the code below and paste in text file and save it as Test.js inside Layouts folder. Replace the list name, list id and column names (internal column names) with yours in the code.

   ```
   var listName ="TestCL";
   var listId = "{935F312E-1ECA-4D7A-B7ED-EB0C1995B3F9}";
   var hyperLinkColName = "EmailColumn";
   var choiceColNameToChange = "ChoiceYN";
   var listItem;
   var hyperlinkInnerHtml;

   var options = {
       OnPostRender: function (ctx)  
       { 
       changeChoiceColOnClick(hyperLinkColName,choiceColNameToChange);
       }
   };

   changeChoiceColOnClick = function(hypLnkColumnInternalName ,choiceColInternalName){

       for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; i++) {
           listItem = ctx.ListData.Row[i];
           var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
           var row = document.getElementById(iid);
           if(row){
               var hypLnkColumnValue = listItem[hypLnkColumnInternalName];
                   if(hypLnkColumnValue.length > 0)
                   {
                       var listItemId = listItem.ID;
                       $("a[href='" + hypLnkColumnValue + "']").attr("onClick","ResetChoiceToNo('" + listItemId + "','" + choiceColInternalName + "')");
                   }
               }

       }
   }
   function ResetChoiceToNo(listItemId , choiceColInternalNameToReset)
   {
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
       var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

       this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(listItemId);

       oListItem.set_item(choiceColInternalNameToReset, 0);

       oListItem.update();

       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   }

   function onQuerySucceeded() {

       alert('Item updated!.Please refresh the page or reload the page in code');
   }

   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

       alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }


   // Create a function for customizing the Field Rendering of our fields 
   CustomizeFieldRendering = function () {  
       console.log("in CustomizeFieldRendering");
       // Register the rendering template
       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(options); 
   }; 

   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomizeFieldRendering, 'clienttemplates.js');
   ```
4. Edit the page having the list and add JS link under Miscellaneous to the file you saved in point 2 in layouts folder. /_layouts/15/Test.js

[image]

5. See the image of the list.

[image]